# Saving Artwork only when Saving for Web

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, save

I am working on some artwork to use in my web project and I am using the latest version of Adobe Illustrator.

When I go to `File > Save for Web` I get the following:

[image: saving for web]

As you can see the Art-board space around my artwork also shows! Is there a way I can tell illustrator that I'm only interested in saving the artwork?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just uncheck Clip to Artboard box on the right side of save for web window, it actually even shows in your screenshot. After unchecking it should crop it to your image.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thanks @jjjuho :)

Answer (score 1):

Deselect all and try `Objects -> Artoboards -> Fit to Artwork Bounds`

then try to save again.

Comment: That would work, but I don't really want to re-size my art-board as I like that white space when working / editing the artwork, and I don't want to have to keeping adding it back after each save.

Comment: When I do "Export" and choose JPG or PNG it ignores the Artboard and export only the art (CS6).

Comment: Nice that seems to do it! But that doesn't give you the ability to re-size artwork which I need :(

Comment: Actually, I would recommend next workflow - turn on Pixel Preview (Ctrl+Alt+Y). Do an actual size (in pixels, via Transform pannel), check how it looks in pixels (instead vector), fix blurry edges and export .